# Execute event when iphone application is not active

Tags: iphone

I want a timer to keep executing in background even when the application is not active. And depending upon some conditions I want to fire a local push notification. How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that is not possible. 
first, you register the local push notification and its fire date when your app is active and you can not do it when your app is not active.
second, when you register a local push notification the iphone os is in charge to fire it and not your app.
third, background activity is permitted only for 3 things - music, VOP and navigation, thats all.

if you can explain exactly what you want to achieve we might try to help you in other ways.

hope it will help
shani

Comment: Hi shani, i want the timer to keep executing even when the application is not active(minimized) and on the basis of some condition generate the local push notification

Comment: and which does not look possible according to you. :-(

Comment: Hi, what are exactly the conditions you are listening to?

Comment: i want to fetch some data from a rss feed and check if it is different from already present data, I want to generate a notification. I want to do this periodically (e.g every hour)

Comment: the only thing i can think of is to do that check on an external server. lets say that every time that the user sends the app to the background it sends a time stamp to the server and the same thing when it is opened. then you check when there is a new data and send a remote notification to all the devices that are close at that time??????